# How to completly remove and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I've been having a few issues with Ubuntu Software Center and need to do a complete reinstall of it. I tried "sudo apt-get purge software-center" but that said it would remove the Ubuntu desktp. So how can I completely remove it (config files and everything) then reinstall it?

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having and what makes you think reinstalling software center will fix it? This is not windows and reinstalling things rarely, if ever, fixes problems.

Comment: Well it's only just a few little things that would probably be insignificant to most. I would just like to know how to completely reinstall it is all. @bodhi.zazen

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu-desktop is a meta-package. Removing it *will not* actually make your desktop inoperable.

Your method is correct, though I use explicit flags when I remove:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
```

This will remove config files as well as the package. To install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

You could also add ubuntu-desktop to that command after the software-center package, if you want to be sure you are still tracking it.

Comment: So running that command won't actually remove anything except the software center? @K. Darien Freeheart

Comment: That will not work.

Comment: How so? All I want is to completely wipe the Software Center off my system, then reinstall it. @bodhi.zazen

Comment: apt-get will remove the dependencies as well.

Comment: It will remove software-center and the ubuntu-desktop metapackage. The metapackage doesn't contain software itself. So technically it will remove more than just software-center, but it won't affect any of your installed software or any programs you use.

Comment: Will I ever need to reinstall the metapackage again? @K.DarienFreeheart

Comment: You do not "need" to re-install the metapackage, but there is no reason not to.

Comment: I'm not 100% of the impact of not having it. I generally remove default packages that remove the metapackage, and my systems work fine. Upgrades have never been an issue for me. So I would generally say "No", but there might be a use case where it would matter. I've never hit one, but YMMV.

Comment: Ok, I removed it and reinstalled it. It now shows up as "Ubuntu Software Centre" not Software Center. Doesn't really matter but kind of confusing. One more little issue, in the drop-down menu by the "Installed" section it still shows a source name that I supposedly removed. Any way to remove it from the list? @K.DarienFreeheart

Comment: Edit - Ok, the source name is now gone, don't know why though... About the name being "Ubuntu Software Centre" apparently it must think I'm in a different country. However, when I first installed Ubuntu it showed up as "Ubuntu Software Center" @K.DarienFreeheart

Answer (score 0):

To remove a package without the dependencies use dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -P <package> --force-depends
```

Then you can re-install it with apt-get